# Cluster index fragment after update table column

Tags: sql-server, indexing, fragment

I have table with cluster index , when update the column with  nvarchar type with exactly same value , index fragmented more than 95 % happend , page number increazed after update and decreaze after rebuild index , i thing its page split , but i cant relize what is the reason .

Comment: What was the column type before you updated it to NVARCHAR type?

Comment: Column type is nvarchar(500) and i checked it with update join and update column value with own , but index fragment happend same as previous.

Comment: nvarchar(500) is pretty poor datatype for a primary key. Surely you can find a better column (or use an identity) for your primary key? A key column that wide is going to be fragmented all the time because it is too wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use where cluse to update specific record to prevent fragmentation.